# Replicating optimization problem done in excel

Tags: optimization

I have sample data like this
# Load the lpSolve package
library(lpSolve)

```
# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
StoreID = 1:5,
Volume = c(1000, 500, 800, 700, 600),
Distance = c(10, 15, 20, 12, 18)
)
```

I need to allocate trucks to each StoreID satisfying all the Volume requirements.
Each truck can carry only 1800 volumes.
Each truck can go to multiple stores.
The ideal solution is Truck1 should be assigned StoreID 1 and 3.
The second Truck should be assigned StoreID 2,4,5.

Please help with R Code to achieve this

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.